# Prove Thales' Theorem using projections

Tags: geometry

Let $r_0,r_1,r_2$ three paralel lines contained in an affine plane, where $r_0,r_1$ are different. Given two lines $t,t'$ not paralel to $r_i$, we take $a_i=r_i\cap t_i$,  $ a_i'=r_i\cap t'_i$ for $i=0,1,2$.
Then $(a_0    a_1  a_2  )$=$(a_0'    a_1'  a_2'  )$.

This is Thales' Theroem, I managed to prove it using coordinates, but now I'm asked to prove it by using that projections and knowing that they preserve the simple ration because the're affine maps. I believe I must study two cases here, one where $a_0\ne a_0'$ and one where $a_0=a_0'$, but I have no idea of how to begin this, I tried drawing a bit but no ideas came to my mind. Can I get a hint?

Comment: This theorem is usually called "[intercept theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem)" in English-speaking countries.